# Spacemacs evil-window key bindings not working?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

I have these keybindings in my `dotspacemacs/user-config` function:

```
;; Modify evil-mode keybindings from hjkl motion to jkl;
;; Motion mappings
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "H" 'evil-window-bottom)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "L" 'evil-window-top)
;;
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "h" 'evil-repeat-find-char)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "j" 'evil-backward-char)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "k" 'evil-next-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "l" 'evil-previous-line)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map ";" 'evil-forward-char)
;; Window mappings
(define-key evil-window-map "J" 'evil-window-move-far-left)
(define-key evil-window-map "K" 'evil-window-move-very-bottom)
(define-key evil-window-map "L" 'evil-window-move-very-top)
;;
(define-key evil-window-map "j" 'evil-window-left)
(define-key evil-window-map "k" 'evil-window-down)
(define-key evil-window-map "l" 'evil-window-up)
(define-key evil-window-map ";" 'evil-window-right)
```

However, when I do `SPC w`, the `evil-window-*` bindings aren't what I've defined them as here. They are still mapped to `hjkl`, instead of `jkl;` like I'd prefer. The motion mappings work just fine. I'm not really sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Maybe I was a little with the earlier this guesswork, seeing how your movement keybindings are successfully overwritten...

Anyway, what I noticed: the `evil-window-map` you are binding your keys to is called with `C-w` rather than `SPC w`. Your window bindings will show up there.

If you want to alter what is available under `SPC w`, you should edit the leader key map, for example:

```
   (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "wj" 'evil-window-left)
```

Hope this helps.
You might need to load these configurations *after* evil is loaded. To do so, see my original answer below.

---

Original answer:

I think your keybindings are being overwritten when `evil` as is loaded *after* your code is executed.

Try having your configuration executed later by wrapping the relevant lines like so:

```
 (with-eval-after-load 'evil
  ;; code goes here
  )
```